# DateTime AddMinutes method not working

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

The purpose of my method is to get the currentTime, and set it back for 20 minutes. For what I can see, my method is correct, but the output shows something else.

This i my code:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
double minuts = -20;
currentTime.AddMinutes(minuts);

Console.WriteLine("Nuværende tid: "+currentTime);
```

The output are as followed:

```
25-11-2011 14:01:54
```

My result should be:

```
25-11-2011 13:41:54.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

#### Description

The AddMinutes function returns a DateTime.

> `DateTime.AddMinutes` Method
>   Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of minutes to the value of this instance.

#### Sample

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
double minuts = -20;
currentTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minuts);

Console.WriteLine("Nuværende tid: "+currentTime);
```

#### More Information

- [DateTime.AddMinutes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, this is why I hate languages where you can call a function/method that returns a value and not use the value.  It's there for a reason :-)

Comment: this do not depends on the language, only the pattern. You can do this in always any programming language.

Comment: You help me. That was me stupid to forgot that Addminutes return a datetime.

Answer (score 4):

```
...
currentTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minuts); 
...
```

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
currentTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minuts);
```

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` is "immutable", what that means is you can never modify an existing instance, only make new ones. Strings are the same, for example. So you need to use the result of the `AddMinutes` call, which gives you your existing `currentTime` with the `minuts` variable applied.

```
currentTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minuts);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`AddMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx) returns a new `DateTime` object so you need:

```
    DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
    double minuts = -20;
    DateTime newTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(minuts);

    Console.WriteLine("Nuværende tid: "+newTime);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
currentTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5.0f);
```